# Do methods such as viewWillDisappear() require the override keyword?

Tags: ios, swift, events, overriding, viewcontroller

When adding methods such as viewWillAppear() to a ViewController, is it necessary to use the override keyword on the method?

In the ViewController, I add:

```
func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doStuff), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
}
```

... and XCode (surprisingly?) does not complain/warn.

However if I change it to:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doStuff), name: .UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)
}
```

...then XCode says:

> Argument names for method 'viewWillAppear(animated:)' do not match those of overridden method 'viewWillAppear' ... insert '_'

... ***which, if I fix, then everything is fine,*** but I'm just curious would it have been considered okay to just leave it the way it was in the first place?

I would have expected only one option to work, not both.

Can you explain that? Because the documentation does not explain that as far as I can tell.

Signing off,

A Confused Boober Bunz.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is typo error

Comment: Well maybe I'm fixing the typo error!  Simmer down! :)

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya No it is not a typo. If it were a typo, OP should be able to figure out that he/she had a typo when Xcode showed the error message. Clearly the OP does not know that argument labels is part of the method signature.

Comment: @Sweeper doesn't it ? if he/she mistyped method

Comment: *"would it have been considered okay to just leave it the way it was in the first place?"* – that's easy to figure out (using your thinking cap :-) Set a breakpoint and check if it is hit (or add a print statement).

Comment: Correct... but why didn't XCode give a warning that I was using a function of the same name as an override method?

Comment: @BooberBunz Just follow the steps -> `Cmd + click` on UIViewController class (it will take you to swift UIKit library  methods of UIViewController) -> FIND viewWillDisappear some thing like `open func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)` copy and paste it in your View controller

Comment: @BooberBunz: Because `func foo(x: Int) {}` and `func foo(_ x: Int) {}` are two different and unrelated methods.

Comment: I editted the question so you guys aren't getting thrown off by irrelevant things. Thanks!

Comment: @BooberBunz, and now question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: ok i rolled it back.  Please dont downvote... I didn't understand that argument labels are part of the method signature OK. Mkay.

Comment: @BooberBunz , I gave this an upvoted. My Bunz were confused also.   This helped.  For what ever reason Xcode 10 stopped with the autocomplete feature.  I think I am bridging in a swift file into an older Objective-C project and the compiler could not find the label viewWillAppear(...) signature.  So prashant-tukadiya helped with his suggestion of going to UIViewController.  This is a valid problem that comes up from time to time - especially when bridging - I have seen it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why Xcode did not complain is because your `viewWillAppear` has a different signature from the `viewWillAppear` in `UIViewController`. The signature of your version is

```
viewWillAppear(animated:)
```

while the one declared in `UIViewController` is:

```
viewWillAppear(_:)
```

So in the end you are creating a brand new method. This does not conflict with any of the `UIViewController` methods, so Xcode doesn't complain even if you don't write `override`.

To answer your question of whether it's "okay": It's not okay if you want your code to be run when the view did appear. It's ok if you don't care about the code in your `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @BooberBunz I didn't downvote, but if you hover over the downvote button, you'll see what kind of questions will be downvoted: "does not show any research effort", "not clear or not useful". Apparently that's what people think of your question.

Comment: yeah sorry... its hit or miss... I was actually cut/pasting code that was given in an answer to my previous question and ran to stackoverflow too quickly.  I'm smart! :D

Comment: Personally I think this is a bad language feature... you should NOT be allowed to have a method with the same name as a delegate/override/callback/interface method (or whatever)... even if the arguments are spelled different.  You can see why.  Because smart people get confused.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the underscore, in my case this is the final updated method:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    cameraSessionController.startCamera()
}
```